How would I be able to use JavaScript in order to overlay an explosion gif as a callable function?
I have a countdown timer on my website, and I want it to overlay a generic explosion GIF when the timer runs out. I have a function call when it runs out, now I just need to know what will go in that function.
I'm really new to JavaScript and web dev as a whole, so I don't have any idea how to go about this.
I've tried looking online but all of the docs I've found don't provide any help or don't make any sense.
This is the code that I have so far:
window.onload = function () {
    var time = 299, // your time in seconds here
        display = document.querySelector('#timer');
    startTimer(time, display);
};

function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            
            // This is the part that will call the explosion function.
        }
    }, 1000);
}


You should create an element as overlay in HTMl with position: fixed; inset: 0; and hide it by default. You then can use in JS classList.remove() to remove the class that hides the overlay so it will be visible.
You need to stop the interval if the time reaches 0 with clearInterval.
I also refactored your code:


window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  startTimer();
})

function startTimer() {
  let time = 10; // reduced the timer for demo reasons
  const timerInterval = setInterval(function () {
    let minutes = twoDigitNumber(parseInt(time / 60));
    let seconds = twoDigitNumber(time % 60);

    timer.value = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;

    if (time === 0) {
      clearInterval(timerInterval);
      overlay.classList.remove('d-none');
    }
    
    time--;
  }, 1000);
}

function twoDigitNumber(number) {
  return number.toString().padStart(2,0);
}
#overlay {
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  &.d-none {
    display: none;
  }
}
<body>
  <div id="overlay" class="d-none">
    <img src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
  </div>
  
  <output id="timer"></output>
</body>



Refactor Informations
You should not use on events such as onload. Those events can only exist once and they will overwrite each other. It might not seem important in your "little" project but it will teach you wrong habits. You should always use addEventListener to append events. That way you will not overwrite other events that might have been added. A common reason for an unintentional overwriting of an event is another script often written by other programmers.
You should and do not need to hand over parameters all the time. The only place where this might happen is with the usage of a config file. In that case you should not use ladder logic but object-oriented programming using Class.
With the ladder logic you used, you should have the time variable (actually a let not a var) inside your discrete function. Same for the element which should be a const! However, referencing that element is not needed as you can call elements on their id directly in ES6.
Do not write repetitive code such as:
minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

Instead, write a discrete function.
if (--timer < 0) { ... }

This is hardly readable as it is easy to miss your decrementing. You write code not for machines but to be readable for other humans. So write longer code if it makes the code more readable and try not to hide simple things instead of writing them into a new line!
display is a method in JS. it is not a suitable name for a variable to constant. Besides that, it is not an intuitive name for a timer. Always choose meaningful names that explain what the name is used for.

Is &.d-none  preprocessor syntax? Also, you need to declare timerInterval outside the functions (globally) so that clearInterval(timerInterval) can access timerInterval.

@zer00ne yes and no. &.d-none technically is a preprocessor syntax but it is also a Level 4 CSS Selector Module Level 4: CSS Nesting. As such it works in every major browser without SASS/LESS.

@zer00ne for your second statement Also, you need to declare timerInterval outside the functions (globally) so that clearInterval(timerInterval) can access timerInterval - you're incorrect here. You don't need a global variable as it works here without. We're are block scoped (or function scoped) so clearInterval actually knows the constant because of this scope. The error was caused by a typo Intervall instead of Interval.

Oops I was looking at my code and then assumed yours had two named functions I need to go to bed .

It can be achieve by many ways but simplest is by creating a html div with some class or id and inside that div add image/video/gif of your explosion and set it to display: none; and whenever we want to show the explosion, set the display to block/flex as per your need.
Below is working example. Your counter also working in negative values, I haven't fixed it by thinking it might be intentional.


window.onload = function() {
  var time = 10, // your time in seconds here
    display = document.querySelector('#timer');
  startTimer(time, display);
};

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  if (timer > 0) {

    setInterval(function() {

      minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
      seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

      minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
      seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

      display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

      if (--timer < 0) {
        document.querySelector(".explosionDiv").style.display = "flex";
      }
    }, 1000);
  }

}
body {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.mainDiv {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.explosionDiv {
  display: none;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  inset: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  z-index: 10;
}
<h2 id="timer">
  Clean Code Editor
</h2>

<div class="explosionDiv">
  Explosion Image/Video/gif here
</div>




overlays should be position: fixed; inset: 0; not absolute to the body. If you would scroll down you would miss the overlay.

@tacoshy Thanks  I didn't know that, also have updated above code.

PS: inset: 0 is a short form for top: 0, right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;. So you can remove the top, width and height properties.

Assuming that the gif is inside a <img> element and has its id attribute set to "elementId", you can do the following to display the gif:
function displayExplosion() { 
  document.getElementById('elementId').style.display = 'block';
}

Also, be sure to handle your timer, i.e, reset it or clear it. Have a look at this for more info.
To learn more about the display css property, visit: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display



window.onload = function() {
  var time = 9, // your time in seconds here
    display = document.querySelector('#timer');
  startTimer(time, display);
};

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  var countdown = setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      clearInterval(countdown);
      showExplosion();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function showExplosion() {
  var explosion = document.getElementById('explosion');
  explosion.style.display = 'block';
}
#explosion {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1000;
  /* Make sure it overlays other content */
}

#timer-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}
<div id="timer-container">
  <div id="timer"></div>
  <img id="explosion" src="path/to/your/explosion.gif" alt="Explosion">
</div>



please refer the above code

It appears that OP's code is here and the only thing that's needed is another function to add an exploding gif to which there's no evidence of any attempt to do so. I realized this after I finished answering this half baked question. In the example below a <dialog> element is used as an overlay containing the gif which is revealed by function explosion() once the function countdown() is finished with the given duration. All required elements are dynamically added so the minimal amount of HTML is needed. Details are commented in the example below.


// Define the interval outside the functions
let tick = null;

/**
 * It dynamically adds a <time> element to display a countdown
 * lasting a number of given seconds. When the countdown is
 * complete it calls the explosion(node) function.
 * @param {number} duration - The number of seconds.
 * @param {DOM object} node - A reference to an element that
 *                            <time> and <dialog> will be added
 *                            to.
 *                            If nothing is passed, <body> is
 *                            the default.
 * @return {function} explosion(node)
 */
function countdown(duration, node = document.body) {

  // Create and add <time> to DOM
  const timer = document.createElement("time");
  node.append(timer);

  // Redifine tick as a setInterval() function
  tick = setInterval(function() {
    /**
     * Calculate duration into minutes and seconds then 
     * convert min and sec into strings.
     */
    let min = parseInt(duration / 60, 10).toString();
    let sec = parseInt(duration % 60, 10).toString();

    // Pad min and sec with a zero if they are a single digit.
    min = min.padStart(2, "0");
    sec = sec.padStart(2, "0");

    // Display min and sec in <time>
    timer.textContent = min + ":" + sec;

    // Decrement duration by the interval⃰ 
    --duration;

    /**
     * If the given number of seconds is 0 or less, call
     * explosion() and pass the @param node.  
     */
    if (duration <= 0) {
      return explosion(node);
    }
    // ⃰This is the interval which is 1000ms = 1s
  }, 1000);
}

/**
 * It creates a <dialog> and <img> and adds it to the given
 * element, reveals the <dialog>, and stops countdown().
 * @param {DOM object} node - See @param node above.
 */
function explosion(node) {

  // Create <dialog> and <img>
  const overlay = document.createElement("dialog");
  const image = new Image();
  image.src = "https://i.ibb.co/F8NCxsV/nuke.gif";

  // Add <img> to <dialog> and <dialog> to the given node
  overlay.append(image);
  node.append(overlay);

  // Stop setInterval() function
  clearInterval(tick);
  // Reveal <dialog>
  overlay.showModal();
  return false;
}

/**
 * Call countdown()
 * First @param is 10 seconds.
 * Second @param is not passed so it defaults to <body>
 */
countdown(10);
:root {
  font: 5vmin/1 Consolas;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

time {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: red;
}

dialog {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
  background: transparent;
}

dialog::backdrop {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}




so you can use ClearInterval() and need to change some code.
var countDown = setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
            
        // This is the part that will call the explosion function.
        ClearInterval(countDown);
        // Please call a callback function here.
    }
}, 1000);


You miss the question. The question was not how to stop a timer!

yeah, sorry for that, so you need to add some HTML code and JavaScript code.
